# Postman Testing

Tags: java, postman

I am trying to test in Postman a rest end point url. I am unable to upload a file and 2 JSON Objects, both at a time from Postman.

I can do it separately, I mean I can choose a file from **form-data**(Postman). Can send a JSON object from **raw**(Postman).But I cannot do at a time both.

Can some one please help me on this.

Comment: What does your JSON object look like? You might have to break it down into each individual key-value pair and fill them in the `form-data` inputs, which is similar to how you would might do it in a browser.

Comment: Thanks Azro, For your reply....In the form-data there are two fields either text or file, but I need JSON reading field.

Comment: Example of the code I am using: @PostMapping("/upload")
 public FileUploadResponse scanupload(@RequestPart("uploadFile") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("ecmsDocumentInfo") EcmsDocument ecmsDoc,
   @RequestPart("requestInfo") RequestInfo reuestInfo, BindingResult result) throws Exception {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **Body**->**form-data** you can put your file and a `JSON` file(`.json` extension) with your `JSON` content.